# How to make an accent insensitive search in elasticsearch with nest c# client?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm an elasticsearch newbie.

Lets say we have a class like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string name;
}
```

And we have 2 documents which have names like **"Ayşe"** and **"Ayse"**.

Now, **I want to be able to store names with their accents but when I search want to be able take results of accent insensitive query as accent sensitive results**.

For ex: When I search for **"Ayse"** or **"Ayşe"**, it should return **both "Ayşe" and "Ayse"** as they stored (with accent).

Right now when I search for "Ayse" it only returns "Ayse" but I want to have "Ayşe" as a result too.

When I checked elasticsearch documentation, I see that folded properties is needed to be used to achive that. But I couldn't understand how to do it with Nest attributes / functions.

BTW I'm using AutoMap to create mappings right now and if it is possible I want to be able to continue to use it.

I'm searching for an answer for 2 days right now and couldn't figure it out yet.

What/where changes are required? Can you provide me code sample(s)?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I figured out how to use analyzers to create sub fields of a property and achive results with term based query against sub fields.

Now, I know I can do a multi field search but **is there a way to include sub fields with full text search?**

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html this should help

Comment: I think what I need is like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html but I don't understand how to use it with .net because I have only 1 property which is name and don't have name.folded. So I can not query name.folded by linq. And also in my real situation I have tons of properties to query, so I'm wondering if there is a way to store only original value like 'Ayşe' and query like 'Ayse' and get the 'Ayşe' as a result. There are two attribute parameters of Nest.String: Analyzer and SearchAnalyzer. I have tons of questions to ask about it

Comment: @DhruvPal Because I don't have all the possibilities recorded, the method you mentioned is not seem to be useful for my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure an analyzer to perform analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) on the text at index time, index this into a [multi_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields_2) to use at query time, as well as keep the original source to return in the result. Based on what you have in your question, it sounds like you want a custom analyzer that uses the [`asciifolding` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html) to convert to ASCII characters at index and search time.

Given the following document

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Setting up a custom analyzer can be done when an index is created; we can also specify the mapping at the same time

```
client.CreateIndex(documentsIndex, ci => ci
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(1)
        .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        .Analysis(analysis => analysis
            .TokenFilters(tokenfilters => tokenfilters
                .AsciiFolding("folding-preserve", ft => ft
                    .PreserveOriginal()
                )
            )
            .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                .Custom("folding-analyzer", c => c
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .Filters("standard", "folding-preserve")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Document>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Name)
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .String(ss => ss
                            .Name("folding")
                            .Analyzer("folding-analyzer")
                        )
                    )
                    .NotAnalyzed()
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here I've created an index with one shard and no replicas (you may want to change this for your environment), and have created a custom analyzer, `folding-analyzer` that uses the standard tokenizer in conjunction with the `standard` token filter and a `folding-preserve` token filter that perform ascii folding, storing the original tokens in addition to the folded tokens (more on why this may be useful in a minute).

I've also mapped the `Document` type, mapping the `Name` property as a `multi_field`, with default field `not_analyzed` (useful for aggregations) and a `.folding` *sub-field* that will be analyzed with the `folding-analyzer`. The original source document will also be stored by Elasticsearch by default.

Now let's index some documents

```
client.Index<Document>(new Document { Id = 1, Name = "Ayse" });
client.Index<Document>(new Document { Id = 2, Name = "Ayşe" });

// refresh the index after indexing to ensure the documents just indexed are
// available to be searched
client.Refresh(documentsIndex);
```

Finally, searching for *Ayşe*

```
var response = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .Fields(f => f
                .Field(c => c.Name.Suffix("folding"))
            )
            .Query("Ayşe")
        )
    )
);
```

yields

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.163388,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "documents",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.163388,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Ayşe"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "documents",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.3038296,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Ayse"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Two things to highlight here:

Firstly, the `_source` contains the original text that was sent to Elasticsearch so by using `response.Documents`, you will get the original names, for example

```
string.Join(",", response.Documents.Select(d => d.Name));
```

would give you "Ayşe,Ayse"

Secondly, remember that we preserved the original tokens in the asciifolding token filter? Doing so means that we can perform queries that undergo analysis to match accent insensitively but also take into account accent sensitivity when it comes to scoring; in the example above, the score for *Ayşe* matching *Ayşe* is higher than for *Ayse* matching *Ayşe* because the tokens *Ayşe* and *Ayse* are indexed for the former whilst only *Ayse* is indexed for the latter. When a query that undergoes analysis is performed against the `Name` property, the query is analyzed with the `folding-analyzer` and a search for matches is performed

```
Index time
----------

document 1 name: Ayse --analysis--> Ayse

document 2 name: Ayşe --analysis--> Ayşe, Ayse  


Query time
-----------

query_string query input: Ayşe --analysis--> Ayşe, Ayse

search for documents with tokens for name field matching Ayşe or Ayse
```

Comment: Hi @RossCam, there is a problem with this example, searching "Ayşe" gets results but searching "Ayse" doesn't. I tried to use analyzer function of query with custom analyzer and default one too but no luck. This problem is the same problem with my original problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524988/indexing-and-full-text-searching-in-elasticsearch-without-dialitics-using-c-shar

Comment: As always, thank you for your detailed answer Russ. But I'm not accepting this as answer because searching "ayse" doesn't get any results back.

Comment: This works for me using NEST 2.3.1 against Elasticsearch 2.3.2 - just tested it again for certainty. What version of NEST are you using and against what version of Elasticsearch? What do the mappings and analyzers look like for your index i.e. if you run `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/{index-name}"` what do you get?

Comment: thank you. You were right. It wasn't about version (I was using 2.3.1) It was about searching with the right analyzer. Now it is working! Thank you. In the mean time, because of this problem I know so much more about elasticsearch and know more about how to configure mapping better. I'm using _all field to search and so I'm using  AllField function to configure analyzer. Thank you thank you thank you! I'm excited like a child :-)

Comment: you should try to use ICU folding not asciifolding

Comment: @dzomba ICU folding ++